# Drawing floor and ceiling functions

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Graph the following functions:

$$: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},()=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+1$$

$$: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},()=2\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$$

$$ : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},  () = \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor + ⌈⌉$$

$$ : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},  () = ⌈⌉ − \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$$

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is how I think I should go about doing the task:

To graph the function $$: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},()=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+1$$, you would plot points corresponding to the ordered pairs $(x, \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+1)$ for various values of $x$. For example, if $x=2.5$, then $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+1=3+1=4$, so you would plot the point $(2.5, 4)$. You would continue this process for various values of $x$ to create a graph of the function.

To graph the function $$: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},()=2\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$$, you would plot points corresponding to the ordered pairs $(x, 2\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor)$ for various values of $x$. For example, if $x=2.5$, then $2\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=2(2)=4$, so you would plot the point $(2.5, 4)$. You would continue this process for various values of $x$ to create a graph of the function.

Etc.

Comment: One of the most simple technique is to divide the case: $x$ is an integer or not. Then you can easily draw the graph. More specifically, if $x$ is not an integer, write $x = n+\alpha$ where $n$ is an integer and $\alpha\in(0, 1)$.

Comment: $\lfloor 2.5 \rfloor = 2$

Comment: ⌊x⌋ is the greatest integer less than or equal to x,⌊2.4⌋=2,
⌊-2.4⌋=-3. by hand you notice that from x to x+1 not included, floor(x) is x. ⌊2⌋=2, ⌊2.99999999999999999⌋=2, ⌊3⌋=3. so it's a constant (1) between 1 and 2 not included, then the constant (2) changes between 2 and 3 not included. here is the graph https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/903486480075354182/1032966184829730936/floo.png

Comment: then we add 1 to the constant and we can graph f(x), do you know if i should have a full circle at the ends of the lines, or non-full circles?

Comment: i was told i can add full circles at the beginning of each segment

Comment: When you graph the function $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$, each left endpoint is closed and each right endpoint is open.

Comment: Doug M pointed out that $\lfloor 2.5 \rfloor = 2$  because in your first calculation, you converted it's value to $3$ instead. However, in the second calculation, you did give the correct value of $2$. You use a filled circle to indicate the value of the function at that point. If a line segment goes up to this point, and further, the value of the function at that point is the same, then you use a filled circle. But if the line segment approaches a point, but at that point itself, the function has a different value, then you use an empty circle.

Comment: For the first two graphs. for integer values of $x$, there will be two line segments ending at $x$. The value of the function at $x$ will match one of those segments, but will not match the other segment. For those, you fill the circle on the segment that is matched, and do not fill the other circle. However, the last two problems are trickier. I will leave it to you to figure what is going on. Once you do, if you are not sure how to graph, I can explain (but you will need to include "@" followed by my user name in the comment, so that I will be notified of your reply, such as: @bittscoterie)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Hi, sorry, I am not sure how to graph it. If we have $x=0.9,\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor  +\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor  \rightarrow \left\lfloor 0.9\right\rfloor  +\left\lfloor 0.9\right\rfloor  =2\left\lfloor 0.0\right\rfloor  =2\left( 0\right)  =0$, then we get $\left( 0.9,\  \left\lfloor 0.9\right\rfloor  \right)  \Leftrightarrow \left( 0.9,\  0\right)$, am I right?

Comment: Look carefully. None of your questions is directly about $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor$ (yes, one is about $2\lfloor x \rfloor$, but there is no reason to write that as a summation). And when you examine the correct function, examine how it behaves on *both sides* of integer arguments, not just one, and also look at how it behaves at the integer argument itself.